# Identify Terminals Used in this Music Video

Tags: identify-this-computer

I was watching music videos on YouTube and noticed these machines in the [video for the song *Who's Behind the Door*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofz0iJQd-xU) by the band [Zebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_(American_band)).  The song was released on their album in 1983, but I don't know when the video was made.  They're an American band from New Orleans.

There are two kinds of monitor present, or possibly two completely different terminals, but I suspect they're from the same manufacturer.  They keyboard is interesting because it has a separate strip of keys between the main keys and the keypad.  A nameplate is visible in the keyboard closeup, but illegible to me.

[image: One with a box]

[image: Different monitor, no box]

[image: Close-up of keyboard]

Comment: Two questions hardly count as a flood. I suggest you create another question specifically for the other image and link this question to that one showing that they are from a common source. I think the other device is another microcomputer since there would be no need for a what is plainly a disk interface on the right side of the screen on a terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, the first and third picture clearly shows an [Epson QX-10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epson_QX-10) of 1983. It's not a terminal, but a Z80 based CP/M system.

[image]

(Picture taken from Wikipedia)

No idea so far about the second picture, wich in fact may be a terminal. Or something complete different, like a video telephone. I think I remember a similar looking one from back then. For the video they changed the setup at least for a later scene (2:38) were this other systems screen is put atop the QX-10. Maybe because it could display a TV signal right away - for that symbol thingy.

Comment: Very good, thanks.  I wonder whether I should post the other thing as a separate question?

Comment: @LAK Usually separate questions per Item are the best way to get good answers. Just don't flood the site in a single day ...